# Codeigniter memcached driver: slow work on lock

Tags: php, memcached, codeigniter-3

I turned on `memcached` on `codeigniter`. It works fine but I noticed some delay on script execution. I debugged Session_memcached_driver and figured that it stuck for a few seconds on line 330-336

```
    do
    {
        if ($this->_memcached->get($lock_key))
        {
            sleep(1);
            continue;
        }

        if ( ! $this->_memcached->set($lock_key, time(), 300))
        {
            log_message('error', 'Session: Error while trying to obtain lock for '.$this->_key_prefix.$session_id);
            return FALSE;
        }

        $this->_lock_key = $lock_key;
        break;
    }
    while (++$attempt < 30);
```

Obviously, it waiting for release and that takes a few seconds(5-7 seconds). Maybe I don't close something what I should or use CI session mechanism in wrong way? 
 PHP 7, Linux, CI 3.1.4

Answer (score 1):

I had absulutely the same issue. 
Delay is caused by touch() command. If you look at driver line 109:

$this->_memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, TRUE);

Comment out temporarily to see, if it solves issue. if YES, you need to update libmemcached on server. After upgrade, restart web server .

I had libmemcached 1.0.16, upgraded to 1.0.18
If you DONT upgrade, but just comment out that line, session time will NOT be extended upon user activity and will expire faster - as defined by config file.

Good luck!